# c# wince GetPrivateProfileString

Tags: c#, windows-ce

I used `GetPrivateProfileString` for a .Net(C#) program for normal PCs, and I tried to use this same class for getting information from `config.ini` file.

```
    [DllImport("coredll.dll")]
    private static extern int GetPrivateProfileString(    // GetIniValue 를 위해
        String section,
        String key,
        String def,
        StringBuilder retVal,
        int size,
        String filePath);


    [DllImport("coredll.dll")]
    private static extern long WritePrivateProfileString(  // SetIniValue를 위해
        String section,
        String key,
        String val,
        String filePath);
```

However, `coredll.dll` does not support `GetPrivateProfileString` and `WritePrivateProfileString`.

Is there any way to get this function for `WINCE`?

Please, help me.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> is there any way to get this function for WINCE????

No, I would expect not. WinCe is a 'stripped down' version of Windows and there never was a need to keep backward compatibility with Win 3.1

WinCE does have a registry and it's relatively easy to write your own *simple* ini-file parser.

The much better idea is of course to use a more modern way to store configurations. Like XML.